# Creating an addition loop that stops when it hits a certain number

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming and am trying to make a simple addition program that will continuously add 1 to the previous number (starting at 1) until it hits a number that is defined by the user (in this case it is the user's age).

```
age = int(input("What is your age?: "))
count = 1
while True:
    while count > 0:
        print(count)
        count += 1

    if count == age:
        break
```

I believed I had it working, but for some reason, it continues to add 1 and print out the number without stopping. For example, if I say that my age is 21, I want the program to print out every number starting at 1 until it hits 21.

Comment: You have to indent the `if count == age:` block one tab to the right. It's outside of the loop as-is. And the `while True:` can be dropped entirely.

Comment: @RandomDavis And you will still get stuck in an infinite loop. You don't need 2 while loops, simply, `while count != age: count+=1` is enough. And if you want the syntax with the break, simply remove the second while loop and decrease the indent by one for the print and the increment.

Comment: This will run forever.

Comment: The very definition of "no research effort."  Learn how to use a debugger and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
age = int(input("What is your age?: "))
count = 1
```

This part will always execute, forever loop `while True:`
Just run the below section of your code

```
while count > 0:
    print(count)
    count += 1

    if count == age:
      break
```

Comment: @spirebyte you should do some research on that, and if you can't find anything at all, post it as a separate question (I guarantee that if you google what you're looking for you'll get the answer very quickly though).

Comment: @spirebyte You should learn and try on your own first. Try doing mathematically using modulus then try with code. If still unable to do, happy to help ! And do accept/upvote an answer when you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but the "break" statement is outside your inner loop and never gets reached.  Also, you have a nested `while` loop, which is not needed.  You can do this with a single loop, as shown below:

```
age = int(input("What is your age?: "))
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    print(count)
    if count == age:
        break
```

With this single loop, it will start showing 1 and then show each number till you get to the desired number (age) and then leave the loop.

There are many different ways to solve this problem. Some are better than others. What's most important, when you're first starting out, is that you get something that works.  Then, when you understand it, you can think of ways to make it "better," like maybe by making it shorter or more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You Don not needed to write this style loop for your program. take it easy just with making this While range

```
a = int(input('Enter: '))
x = 0
while x < a:
    x +=1
```

`if` is not necessary for this Script